# (Problem) Smb shows files as directories

Tags: files, directory, sharing, smb

I'm trying to configure an smb share. The problem is that once i connect to the shared hard disk, files in it are shown as directories. Is there a fix for this issue?

Comment: Please provide OS/release detail, and how are files being shown as directories?  Do you mean you get a result of "directory" for a `file` command, you are seeing a "d" as the first character in a `ls -la` or some other way?  Some details will help us understand your issue (copy & paste your commands, or provide a picture via link etc)

Comment: I have ubuntu 20.04. I try to see the contents of the smb share with the file manager. When i get in the shared hdd with the file manager (nautilus), there is a .txt file that is shown as a directory.